# Multiple Forms in Single View

Tags: python, django, django-forms

So I'm using the Django SelectDateWidget currently in my EmployeeForm, but I can only load one form_class in my view. Ideally I'd like to be able to load multiple form_classes in my view, or in some other manner use the SelectDateWidget on my formsets.

**Right now the only widget that works is the one in EmployeeForm. I need help in figuring out how to utilize the widgets found in the three formsets.**

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

## Forms.py

```
from datetime import date
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm, DateInput, DateField, extras
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget
from extra_views import InlineFormSet, CreateWithInlinesView, UpdateWithInlinesView
from extra_views.generic import GenericInlineFormSet
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
from employee_summary.models import Employee, Work_Record, Training_Record, FAA_Certificate

class EmployeeForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        widgets = {
            'hire_date': SelectDateWidget(years=range(date.today().year, 1975, -1)),
            'recurrent_due': SelectDateWidget(years=range(date.today().year, 1975, -1)),
            'super_da_due': SelectDateWidget(years=range(date.today().year, 1975, -1)),
            'red_badge': SelectDateWidget(years=range(date.today().year, 1975, -1)),
        }


class WorkRecordFormSet(InlineFormSet):
    model = Work_Record
    prefix = "work_record"
    extra = 1

    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'start_date': SelectDateWidget(years=range(date.today().year, 1975, -1)),
            'end_date': SelectDateWidget(years=range(date.today().year, 1975, -1)),
        }

class TrainingRecordFormSet(InlineFormSet):
    model = Training_Record
    prefix = "training_record"
    extra = 1

    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'date_earned': SelectDateWidget(years=range(date.today().year, 1975, -1)),
        }

class FAACertificateFormSet(InlineFormSet):
    model = FAA_Certificate
    prefix = "faa_certificate"
    extra = 1

    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'issue_date': SelectDateWidget(years=range(date.today().year, 1975, -1)),
        }
```

## Views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.views.generic import DeleteView, ListView
from extra_views import InlineFormSet, CreateWithInlinesView, UpdateWithInlinesView, SearchableListMixin, SortableListMixin
from extra_views.generic import GenericInlineFormSet
from employee_summary.models import *
from employee_summary.forms import EmployeeForm, WorkRecordFormSet, TrainingRecordFormSet, FAACertificateFormSet
from django.shortcuts import render

class EmployeeCreate(CreateWithInlinesView):
    model = Employee
    form_class = EmployeeForm
    inlines = [WorkRecordFormSet, TrainingRecordFormSet, FAACertificateFormSet]
    template_name = "create.html"
    success_url = '/employees'
```

Answer (score 0):

Formsets don't have a Meta class, and you can't set widgets (or any attributes) on them like that. Instead, you need to define a form class for each of your inline models like you do with the main one, and set the attributes there, and then pass the form class to `inlineformset_factory` to create the formset classes.